# I would like to calculate the difference in days between 2 dates excluding weekends with both dates having NULL in some cases

Tags: sql, ssrs-2012

I have a SSRS report where both dates have `NULL` values so it returns Error. All the other dates are returning the correct value. How do I get past the Error, to return a blank cell? What am I doing wrong?

Code I have tried below:

```
=IIF(IsNothing(Fields!BondRegCSTM_DateRegistered.Value)  AND IsNothing(Fields!CommRecHistory_DateReceived.Value), Nothing,

(DateDiff("d", Fields!BondRegCSTM_DateRegistered.Value, Fields!CommRecHistory_DateReceived.Value))+1-
(DateDiff("ww", Fields!BondRegCSTM_DateRegistered.Value, Fields!CommRecHistory_DateReceived.Value)*2)-
(IIF(DatePart("w", Fields!CommRecHistory_DateReceived.Value) = 1, "1", "0"))-
(IIF(DatePart("w", Fields!BondRegCSTM_DateRegistered.Value) = 1, "1", "0")))
```

Comment: Should the AND be and OR?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use Coalesce function which returns the first value not null.

Answer (score 0):

thank you for the assistance, but I managed to get it sorted. This is what I used and it works perfectly. I have seen a lot of developers have this problem. So I hope this will assist more developers facing this problem :)

**CODE:**

=IIF(Fields!BondRegCSTM_DateRegistered.Value is nothing OR Fields!CommRecHistory_DateReceived.Value is nothing,"",

(DateDiff(DateInterval.day,Iif(IsNothing(Fields!BondRegCSTM_DateRegistered.Value), Fields!BondSales_GrantedDate.Value, 
  Fields!BondRegCSTM_DateRegistered.Value),Iif(IsNothing(Fields!CommRecHistory_DateReceived.Value), Fields!BondSales_GrantedDate.Value, 
  Fields!CommRecHistory_DateReceived.Value))+1)
- (DateDiff(DateInterval.WeekOfYear,Iif(IsNothing(Fields!BondRegCSTM_DateRegistered.Value), Fields!BondSales_GrantedDate.Value, 
  Fields!BondRegCSTM_DateRegistered.Value),Iif(IsNothing(Fields!CommRecHistory_DateReceived.Value), Fields!BondSales_GrantedDate.Value, 
  Fields!CommRecHistory_DateReceived.Value))*2) 
- IIF(Weekday(Fields!BondRegCSTM_DateRegistered.Value,1) = 1,1,0)
- IIF(Weekday(Fields!BondRegCSTM_DateRegistered.Value,1) = 7,1,0)
- IIF(Weekday(Fields!CommRecHistory_DateReceived.Value,1) = 1,1,0)
- IIF(Weekday(Fields!CommRecHistory_DateReceived.Value,1) = 7,1,0)-1)